# How are you supposed to use navigationDestination(for:) with NavigationSplitView (macOS)

Tags: macos, swiftui

How does one use `NavigationSplitView` on macOS to create a master-detail view, with `NavigationLink(value:)` and `.navigationDestination(for:)`? I can’t find an example of this anywhere, and it doesn’t work for me.

```swift
    NavigationSplitView
    {
        List()
        {
            ForEach(self.items, id: \.self)
            { item in
                NavigationLink(value: item)
                {
                    Text(video.name)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Item.self)
        { video in
            Text("Video \(video.name)")
        }
    }
    detail:
    {
        Text("This should not appear")
    }
```

My detail view only shows "This should not appear", and never the selected video name.

**UPDATE:** My actual code has `List(selection: self.$selection)`, where `selection` is `Set<Item>`. Changing it to `List()` allows it all to work. WTF.

Comment: I would suggest updating the code in the question if your real code is different. Why would you allow multiple selection when you only want to navigate to *one* video at a time?

Comment: I don't think `navigationDestination` is supposed to be used with `NavigationSplitView`. Its documentation doesn't mention anything about that. See [`NavigationSplitView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitview) for how to correctly use it.

Comment: Many reasons. I want to be able to select more than one and delete them all, for example.

Comment: Okay but if there is more than 1 video selected, which video do you want to show in the detail view?

Comment: Ideally I get to define a view for that, or maybe create a different navigationDestination for a [Video] type. But that's not really my question.

Comment: We’ll see the docs for navigation split view then. It has an example that shows you exactly how to do this.

Comment: That's not helpful. I looked at the docs.

Answer (score -1):

I think I figured out an appropriate solution. In the view that creates the `NavigationSplitView`, I keep track of the (multi-) selection state. In the `detail:` portion, I check the state, instantiating detail view(s) as appropriate for the selection (or showing a call to action if nothing is selected).

This seems to correctly what I was trying to accomplish with `.navigationDestination`: It only creates views for the selection, and not for every list item instantiated.

```swift
struct
ContentView: View
{
    var
    body: some View
    {
        NavigationSplitView
        {
            List(selection: self.$selection)
            {
                ForEach(self.items)
                {
                    <views for item>
                }
            }
        }
        detail:
        {
            let selection = self.selection.sorted(using: SortDescriptor(\.lastViewed))
            if let video = selection.first
            {
                <views for selelction>
            }
            else
            {
                Text("Select an Item")
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Query  private var items           :   [Video]
    @State  private var selection       :   Set<Video>          =   []
}
```